# BitmapEffect replace with Effects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some code to apply `DropShadowBitmapEffect` to UserControl.

Visual Studio says that `this.BitmapEffect` is ***deprecated*** and we have to use `Effects`.

How it should be done then?

```
DropShadowBitmapEffect myDropShadowEffect = new DropShadowBitmapEffect();
myDropShadowEffect.Color = GetShadowColorValue();
myDropShadowEffect.Direction = 250;
// Set the depth of the shadow being cast.
myDropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 0;
// Set the shadow softness to the maximum (range of 0-1).
myDropShadowEffect.Softness = 1;
// Set the shadow opacity to half opaque or in other words - half transparent.
// The range is 0-1.
myDropShadowEffect.Opacity = 0.7;
// Apply the bitmap effect to the Button.
this.BitmapEffect = myDropShadowEffect; // BitmapEffect is deprecated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DropShadowEffect myDropShadowEffect = new DropShadowEffect();

myDropShadowEffect.Color = GetShadowColorValue();
myDropShadowEffect.Direction = 250;

// Set the depth of the shadow being cast.
myDropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth = 0;

// Set the shadow softness to the maximum (range of 0-1).
// myDropShadowEffect.Softness = 1;

// Set the shadow opacity to half opaque or in other words - half transparent.
// The range is 0-1.
myDropShadowEffect.Opacity = 0.7;

// Apply the effect to the Button.
this.Effect = myDropShadowEffect;
```

I'm not sure what is the equivalent of `Softness`... you can try to adjust the [`BlurRadius`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.dropshadoweffect.blurradius.aspx) value